# Using action buttons on Appbar as tabs.(Flutter)

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

[enter image description here][1]I have been making a project in flutter. I have three action buttons on the Appbar and i want to use the same as tabs on the same Appbar with indicators. How can I achieve this?

[1]: Sample view. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2beQx.png

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Check the image link added recently. The three action buttons above need to be used as tabs.

Comment: Is it okay if you use tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TabController tabController;
final selectedColor = Colors.red;
int currentTab;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  currentTab = 0;
}


//add this function to your build function.

void goTo(int index){
  this.tabController.animateTo(index);
  setState(() {
    this.currentTab = index;
  });
}

// and in your Scaffold:

appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test page 1"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.storage, color: currentTab == 0 ? selectedColor : Colors.white,),
            onPressed: () {
              goTo(0);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_box, color: currentTab == 1 ? selectedColor : Colors.white,),
            onPressed: () {
              goTo(1);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket, color: currentTab == 2 ? selectedColor : Colors.white,),
            onPressed: () {
              goTo(2);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),


body: TabBarView(
        controller: tabController,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.storage),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.account_box),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Can we show the indicator (on selected tab color) on those action buttons just as we do with tabs?

Comment: @DeepShah Modified the answer.

Comment: @DeepShah Can you reply??